# Is there a way to create a bash script that prints out specific paragraphs, i.e. prints a specific block of text between empty lines?

Tags: bash

Working on a script that reads a text file and redirects out a paragraph based on an input. Let's say the input is 2, it would redirect the second paragraph in the text file to another file. The text files wouldn't have headers, they would be plain text paragraphs separated by empty lines. I've been looking at egrep but I'm not very familiar with regex, so I'm not sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `awk`, this function

```
print_nth_paragraph() {
    awk -v RS= -v p="$1" 'NR == p'
}
```

will print the Nth paragraph of its standard input, N being the first and only parameter. A paragraph is delimited by two or more consecutive new lines. Adapt it to your needs.

Comment: This is overly complicated.   By setting RS to the empty string, awk provides the desired behavior.  eg `awk "NR == $1" RS=` will do the trick

Comment: You are right @WilliamPursell, I forgot that, answer fixed. Thanks.